# Riemann's theorem on rational curves

Tags: general-topology, math-history, algebraic-curves, rational-functions

The following passage is from Mathematics and Its History (Page 295)by John Stillwell.

*It was discovered by Riemann that rational curves (curves that can be
parameterized by rational functions) are essentially the same as the sphere, but nonrational curves have “holes” and hence are essentially different. This discovery reveals the role of topology in the study of algebraic curves.*

Can anyone please tell me which theorem is he talking about? If yes, I would further appreciate a proof of it mentioned in some book or article. Thank you!

Comment: It's a consequence of the Riemann Hurwitz formula. It's hard to give an explanation without knowing your background. You can check out Miranda's book on Riemann Surfaces, a proof is given there in the first couple chapters.

Comment: You are asking about the first of the 'consequences' here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Hurwitz_formula

Comment: Kindly excuse my ignorance but, I fail to deduct the statement in question from the formula. I am acquainted with Homology Theory and some basic Algebraic Geometry.

Comment: the statement to show is that there are no regular maps from the sphere to any higher genus curve. A regular map from the complex projective line / the sphere to a curve is the same thing as parametrizing that curve by rational functions.

Comment: Thank you for your help.